# Base Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, class, radix

I am new to C#, C++ and .Net.

I am currently returning to programming from a stint in Networking and Cisco engineering. I used to program on IBM mainframes etc using Cobol, assembler, easytrieve, Rexx and clist etc so the command syntax is reasonably familiar to me as are programming standards and structures.

However I am having quite a bit of trouble getting to grips with the BCL and understanding the various components and what each is designed for and which is best to use in various situations, and in fact how some are actually used and coded.

I am often scratching my head wondering how the code came about from the descriptions I have found about the BCL components. Basically how to use them and code them seems to be a black art with no intuitive means at all.

So my question is, apart from the msdn library, which I am finding to be a bit over complicated for my current needs, is there any good reference book, site, pdf that can give me a reasonable description, usage notes etc of the most commonly used .NET components such as System.IO etc ?

I have read a few book on C# etc and have found a small program that does part of what I need to do in a project I have, requiring acces to devices via RS-232 ports, but when decoding the program I find myself wondering why the person used the components he did and how would I know which components I should use when I make the changes I need to and add in the extra code that I require and how do I actually use these components when I do find them ?

I do realise a lot of this will be down to plain old experience, but a helping hand in the right direction would really help a lot.

Many thanks, George.

Answer (score 2):

[C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578) is good for this, as is [Accelerated C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598733). I think I'd personally recommend Nutshell more.

Note that the next edition of Nutshell is being prepared - but I don't know what the timeframe is. (I'm sure there'll be a slew of books for .NET 4.0.)

(Note of bias: I'm a tech reviewer for C# 4.0 in a Nutshell, so I'm clearly not 100% impartial.)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for that, I wil have a look and see if I can find a copy locally, Aberdeen Scotland.
However, if you have a free copy of the current text, I woul dbe more than happy to accept a donation - ha ha ha ha. ;-)
I bet you get asked that way too often.

Answer (score 0):

I often use Google in preference to the standard Help, there are often better examples out there.

Comment: Yes, I agree on this method too, but I am still looking for the more common place things that I am sure most people wouldnt bother posting information on. And since I am not really used to it yet, I am not really sure what I should be looking for anyway. There isnt anything too complicated about the projrct I have either, so I am sure there is already a component defined for what I need to do. Its just finding the right on and knowing how to use it is the problem at the moment. My inexperience.